# Rails 4 - First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My problem is very similar to [Rails edit.html.erb ArgumentError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26918166/rails-edit-html-erb-argumenterror)

After reading through that page (and about 7 others with the same problem) multiple times and spending several hours trying to fix this, I haven't been able to. The first paragraph worth of error messages on that linked page is identical to the one I'm receiving every time I refresh a user's page.

I'm an absolute novice who's following along with Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails tutorial and am trying to make one small change. Instead of rendering the form for new microposts on the home page, I'm trying to do so on the profile page of users who are logged in. After logging into user #1 and viewing that user's profile page at [URL]/users/1, I receive the aforementioned error message. When viewing that user's profile page while logged out, I don't receive any error messages, and the micropost form is not displayed, as intended. I apologize for asking such a stupid question when I'm sure the answer is obvious to everyone who reads this, except for me. But what am I doing wrong?

Error message details:

```
ArgumentError in UsersController#show
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
app/views/shared/_micropost_form.html.erb:1:in _app_views_shared__micropost_form_html_erb'
app/views/users/show.html.erb:9:in _app_views_users_show_html_erb'

Parameters:
{"id"=>"1"}
```

config/routes.rb:

`resources :microposts,          only: [:create, :destroy]`

views/shared/_micropost_form.html.erb: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCpWd.jpg (Picture #1)

One of many iterations of views/users/show.html.erb that I've tried to use. I've tried so many different things that I believe it doesn't matter which attempt I screenshot; the error message is always the same: (Picture #2 in the previous album; I can only paste two links in this question.)

"show" action under controllers/users_controller.rb, if it's relevant: (Picture #3 in the previous album; I can only paste two links in this question.)

Comment: change to this `<%= form_for (@micropost) do |f| %>`

Comment: After comparing "<%= form_for(@micropost) do |f| %>" to what you wrote, I added a space between "for" and "(@micropost)" on line 1 of _micropost_form.html.erb, saved the changes, and reloaded user #1's profile page. The error message is still identical to the one I've been receiving all along. Did you mean that I should use that code somewhere else?

Comment: where is your render 'microposts_form' lcated ?

Comment: views/shared/_micropost_form.html.erb

Comment: where r u using that form ? in the show ?

Comment: On the profile page of any user who is currently logged in and viewing their own profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting that error because `@micropost` is nil in your partial as it's not actually defined anywhere.

By convention, a local variable with the same name of the partial is created for each item in the partial collection. So, in this case the variable name locally scoped to your collection partial is `micropost`:

**in _micropost.html.erb**

`<%= form_for micropost do |F| %>`

Note that your partial will actually need to be named `_micropost.html.erb`

Comment: I'm sorry for being such an idiot, but I don't understand what you said. I replaced line 1 of _micropost.html.erb (which was previously "<%= form_for(@micropost) do |f| %>") with the line of code you provided, but the error message only changed in such a way that makes me think this is also incorrect. What am I meant to do, specifically, with the "<%= form_for(@micropost) do |f| %>" line of code or the "<%= form_for micropost do |F| %>" line of code that you've just provided? If I could just see the answer, I'm sure I'd finally be able to understand it.

Comment: `<%= form_for micropost do |F| %>` should be correct. But the solution depends on what your partial is named. Can you provide the exact error you're seeing?

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm beginning to see what you're say, if only partially. I've finished defining "@micropost" as "@micropost = current_user.microposts.build if logged_in?" However, I have no idea where I'm meant to place this line of code now. Everywhere I've tried so far hasn't worked; the error message remains the same after every attempt, such as putting it at the very top of _micropost.html.erb

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, you would place `@micropost = current_user.microposts.build if logged_in?` in the controller.

Comment: http://puu.sh/odG3B/99f8ce8578.png Here's the error message. The partial's name is _micropost.html.erb

Comment: Alright, I deleted everything in the _micropost.html.erb partial except for the "<%= form_for Micrpost.new do |F| %>" line which has been brought up 3 times now, and the new error message seems even worse, so I don't think that's the solution. Please tell me EXACTLY which line of which file I am meant to place that line of code in.

Comment: Also, do you know what partial `<%= render @microposts %>` is rendering? There's not enough information from the image provided. That may cause an error too.

Comment: That's definitely the line, but there's not enough information provided to give you an exact solution to the error.

Comment: While backtracking, taking more screenshots, etc, etc, I finally got it to work. I updated controllers/microposts_controller.rb to look like this: http://puu.sh/odHNL/58a3b5ad9c.png And I updated controllers/users_controller.rb to look like this: http://puu.sh/odGXd/e4b2684211.png So it turns out that the error, which insisted that something was wrong with the views, which in turn made us look in the wrong places for a solution, was incorrect, and something was actually wrong with 2 separate controllers. That's life, huh? New page in place of the error page: http://i.imgur.com/lnsITYc.png

Comment: Glad to hear! Best of luck going forward.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the action that originally had your form, you'll see somewhere in that controller that a variable is being set to feed your form with the needed instance variable. If you want to render the form on a different view, you need to make sure that the action that is now responsible for it has it.. (and you can take it out of the original one if you haven't already.